# element.tagName returns undefined

Tags: javascript, undefined, closest, tagname

I have to write a function that will return the closest relative (parent or child) with the given tagName. Here is my code:

```
function closestRelative(parent, relativeName) {
  var closestParent = parent.parentNode.closest(relativeName);
  var childrenElements = parent.children;
  var closetChild;
  
  for(var i=0; i<childrenElements.length; i++) {
    if(childrenElements[i].tagName === relativeName.toUpperCase()){
      closestChild = childrenElements[i];
    }
  }
  
  console.log(closestChild.tagName);
  //if(closestParent) return closestParent.tagName;
  //if(closestChild) return closestChild.tagName;
  //return null;
  return closestChild.tagName.toString();
}

// Example case
document.body.innerHTML = 
'<James>' +
  '<Dave></Dave>' +
  '<Mike></Mike>' +
  '<Sarah></Sarah>' +
'</James>';

let parent = document.getElementsByTagName('James')[0];
let relative = closestRelative(parent, 'Mike');
console.log(relative && relative.tagName); // prints MIKE
```

The console is returning the name of the tag, but the return value is `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to read `.tagName` twice.

In your `closestRelative` function, you are returning `closestChild.tagName.toString()`. Then in your test code, you're doing `relative && relative.tagName`, trying to read it again. Since the function already returned a string, reading `.tagName` results in `undefined`.

You might want to remove the `.tagName` in the last `console.log`, or change `closestRelative` to return the tag itself (`closestChild`) instead of the tag name.